# Regex to match a number or nothing

Tags: java, regex, capturing-group

i need to get a regex that can match something like this :

```
1234 <CIRCLE> 12 12 12 </CIRCLE>

1234 <RECTANGLE> 12 12 12 12 </RECTANGLE>
```

i've come around to write this regex :

```
(\\d+?) <([A-Z]+?)> (\\d+?) (\\d+?) (\\d+?) (\\d*)? (</[A-Z]+?>)
```

It works fine for when i'm trying to match the rectangle, but it doesn't work for the circle

the problem is my fifth group is not capturing though it should be ??

Comment: what do you want as the output, just the numbers or the numbers and the tag contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because only `(\\d*)?` part is optional, but spaces before and after it are mandatory, so you end up requiring two spaces at end, if last `(\\d*)` would not be found. Try maybe with something like

```
(\\d+?) <([A-Z]+?)> (:?(\\d+?) ){3,4}(</[A-Z]+?>)
```

Oh, and if you want to make sure that closing tag is same as opening one you can use group references like `\\1` will represent match from first group. So maybe update your regex to something like

```
(\\d+?) <([A-Z]+?)> (:?(\\d+?) ){3,4}(</\\2>)
//        ^^^^^^^-----------------------^^^ 
//        group 2                       here value need to match one from group 2
```

Comment: @FrancisGroleau I am not sure what you mean. Group 0 represents entire match, while rest of partial matches stored in groups are indexed from 1 so `(\\d+?)` is group `1`, part inside <`([A-Z]+?)`> is group 2, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
(\\d+?) <([A-Z]+?)> (\\d+?) (\\d+?) (\\d+?) (\\d+ )?(</[A-Z]+?>)
```

(I changed the last "\d" group to make the space optional too.)

Answer (score 0):

### Solution for just the numbers:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;

public class Q26005150
{
    private static final Pattern P = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final String s1 = "1234 <CIRCLE> 12 12 12 </CIRCLE>";
        final String s2 = "1234 <RECTANGLE> 12 12 12 12 </RECTANGLE>";

        final List<Integer> l1 = getAllMatches(s1);
        final List<Integer> l2 = getAllMatches(s2);

        System.out.println("l1 = " + l1);
        System.out.println("l2 = " + l2);
    }

    private static List<Integer> getAllMatches(@Nonnull final String s)
    {
        final Matcher m = P.matcher(s);
        final List<Integer> matches = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while(m.find())
        {
            matches.add(Integer.valueOf(m.group(1)));
        }
        return matches;
    }
}
```

### Outputs:

```
l1 = [1234, 12, 12, 12]
l2 = [1234, 12, 12, 12, 12]
```

### [Answer on GitHub](https://github.com/jarrodhroberson/Stack-Overflow/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stackoverflow/Q26005150.java)

### [Stackoverflow GitHub repository](https://github.com/jarrodhroberson/Stack-Overflow)

Answer (score 0):

### Solution for the Numbers and the Tags

```
private static final Pattern P = Pattern.compile("(<\/?(\w+)>|(\d+))");

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final String s1 = "1234 <CIRCLE> 12 12 12 </CIRCLE>";
    final String s2 = "1234 <RECTANGLE> 12 12 12 12 </RECTANGLE>";

    final List<String> l1 = getAllMatches(s1);
    final List<String> l2 = getAllMatches(s2);

    System.out.println("l1 = " + l1);
    System.out.println("l2 = " + l2);
}

private static List<String> getAllMatches(@Nonnull final String s)
{
    final Matcher m = P.matcher(s);
    final List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(m.find())
    {
        final String match = m.group(1);
        matches.add(match);
    }
    return matches;
}
```

### Outputs:

```
l1 = [1234, <CIRCLE>, 12, 12, 12, </CIRCLE>]
l2 = [1234, <RECTANGLE>, 12, 12, 12, 12, </RECTANGLE>]
```

### [Answer on GitHub](https://github.com/jarrodhroberson/Stack-Overflow/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stackoverflow/Q26005150.java)

### [Stackoverflow GitHub repository](https://github.com/jarrodhroberson/Stack-Overflow)

Answer (score -1):

assuming the labels between "<" & ">" has to match and the numbers in between are identical
use this pattern

```
^\d+\s<([A-Z]+)>\s(\d+\s)(\2)+<\/(\1)>$
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/10)

or if numbers in the middle do not have to be identical and or optional:

```
^\d+\s<([A-Z]+)>\s(\d+\s)*<\/(\1)>$
```